# Select all modified files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, codepro

I want to run a plugin on only the modified files in my Eclipse Workspace. I didn't find any shortcut in eclipse to select only modified files (changed after svn checkout) in the package explorer.

I was hoping there would be an option since Eclipse already shows changed packages with a `>` symbol.

**Note**: I want to choose only the changed files and not other files... The Plugin options are not available in the `Team Synchronize` window for SVN.

Comment: I could think of iterating over all elements of your Workspace starting at ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot() and find all modified elements.